# Custom entity access control handler not being called

Tags: entities, 10

I'm trying to define an access control handler for a custom entity, and as far as I can tell it's never being called.

Here's my entity header:

```
  /**
   * Defines the Target entity.
   *
   * @ContentEntityType(
   *   id = "target",
   *   label = @Translation("Target"),
   *   label_collection = @Translation("Targets"),
   *   label_singular = @Translation("Target"),
   *   label_plural = @Translation("Targets"),
   *   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
   *     singular = "@count Target",
   *     plural = "@count Targets",
   *   ),
   *   handlers = {
~_ *     "access" = "Drupal\nm_base\TargetAccessControlHandler",
   *   },
   *   base_table = "nm_target",
   *   admin_permission = "access submissions",
   *   entity_keys = {
   *     "id" = "uuid",
   *   }
   * )
   */
  class Target extends ContentEntityBase {
```

And here's my access controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_base;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandler;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityHandlerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Defines an access controller for the target entity.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\nm_base\Entity\Target.
 */
class TargetAccessControlHandler extends EntityAccessControlHandler implements EntityHandlerInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
    devel_debug('check_access');
    return AccessResult::allowedIf(false);
  }
}
```

Executing an entity query as a non-admin user never triggers that devel_debug. What am I missing?

Comment: Entity queries are SQL and trigger mymodule_query_myentity_access_alter(AlterableInterface $query)

Comment: Huh, so using accessCheck(false) simply stops that hook being called? Is there an OO equivalent to the hook?

Comment: Also if I execute an entity query and then use loadMultiple() to load the entities from the result, shouldn't that trigger the access handler?

Comment: have you tried disable/enable the module, i remember some issue when changing annotaion declaration are not recognized?

Comment: Clearing cache should be enough to reprocess the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the entity query access is handled by some other access handler.
The best way for you to check and investigate further is to check which query access handler is the entity using. Like this:

```
$entityType = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('entity_type_id');
dsm($entityType->getHandlerClasses());
```